# What is the latest Ubuntu or Debian server I can install on proliant dl380 G6

Tags: ubuntu, debian, hp-proliant, nextcloud, odoo

I would like to know what is the latest Debian or Ubuntu server I could install on a dl380 G6 server.

I have to run 2 things on it.

Nextcloud 20 and
Odoo v14 (ERP)

Would this work or not? Or have I bought too old hardware?

I have seen that Debian 5 Lenny can run on this but not a clue if this can handle latest release of nextcloud or odooERP

Comment: That machine is more than 10 years old. While Linux is generally very good at handling old hardware, (they only recently removed the _floppy_ driver!) your performance will be from 10 years ago, and it's going to be quite noisy. I would not have purchased that machine myself. I wouldn't even have taken a free one. That said, you can always try to install anything you want on it.

Comment: So installing Debian buster or Ubuntu 20.04 should be possibe. I know it is old. But it will probably work better than my rpi4 cause backing up that one results without fail in I/o errors.

Comment: Just side note would a dl380 gen 8 be a much better choice? I am looking around the max 250 EUR budget

Comment: If your budget is small, think of the running cost: Such machines use a lot of electricity. You may use a Zotac ZBOX ci329 nano or something similar which uses 1/10 of the energy giving somewhat comparable results.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I got a deal around $250 for it and wanted to make it a staging server. You still think more nuisance than its value?

Comment: dl380 g6 reach end of life 04 / 30 / 2016

Answer (score 1):

Debian 12 is running fine on a large number of G6's where I work. You just need to disable the watchdog with blacklist hpwdt for them to reliably boot. They run with dual 10G fiber connections and can be boosted above 72G of RAM. That said, they aren't fast, they are loud, and they are power hogs. But they're workhorses that just keep on running. We replaced the CPUs with a later version of X5670 on all the boxes giving more cores and some more peppiness. Debian will boost above the 2.93 GHz spec up to around 3.2 GHz on multiple cores. That said, at this point if something on the motherboard dies the chances of getting a replacement motherboard with two functioning CPU sockets seems to be about zero. One socket may work fine, but the second almost invariably has pins that are broken or bent beyond salvage.